# Running many data instances in one go with one .mzn file

Tags: command-prompt, minizinc

Imagine I have a .mzn file name as model.mzn which has some parameters (b,c,d) defined in it and the values for b,c,d parameters are containing in the data file call data1.dzn.
Say for an example:

```
b=[component1];
c=[10,20,30];
d=[30]
```

Imagine now I can get the results from my IDE as well as from the command line.

Imagine I want to run the same model with different data values  for b,c,d (example: I have 3 different data files with different values for b,c & d)

```
data1.dzn :b=[component1];c=[10,20,30];d=[30]
data2.dzn :b=[component2];c=[15,25,35];d=[35]
data3.dzn :b=[component3];c=[40,50,60];d=[70]
```

Is there any way that I can run all this data instances at one go (Not running each model & data separately) and get the optimum answers one go in IDE or command prompt.(Like using a for loop for data instances).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to generalize the encoding of the problem: `b` and `d` could be an array of N elements and `c` a Nx3 dimensional matrix.

**Example:** (for `N=3`)

test.mzn

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% PARAMETERS %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

enum Component = { component1, component2, component3 };
array [1..3] of Component: b;
array [1..3, 1..3] of int: c;
array [1..3] of int: d;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% VARIABLES %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

var 1..3: index :: output_var;
var int: goal;

% dummy optimization goal to showcase
% the encoding    
constraint goal = sum(i in 1..3)(c[index,i]);

%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% GOAL %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%

solve minimize goal;

output [""]
    ++ ["index = \(index);\n"]
    ++ ["b = \(b[index]);\n"]
    ++ ["c = \([c[index, i] | i in 1..3]);\n"]
    ++ ["d = \(d[index]);\n"];
```

test.dzn

```
b = [component1, component2, component3];
c = [|10, 20, 30,
     |15, 25, 35,
     |40, 50, 60|];
d = [30, 35, 70];
```

Output:

```
index = 1;
b = component1;
c = [10, 20, 30];
d = 30;
----------
==========
```